# how to change value of one input text field (in one html table) based on a specific value of another input text field (present in another html table)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have one html table which has one row. This row has two TDs which hold their own tables within them (Each having 10 rows with 10 input fields). I want to change value of another respective text field based on value change in first field onblur().

First field-. It takes value from an Array of size 10

```
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<table width="85%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="inputTable">
<tr>
<td width="60%">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<c:set var="input1" value="${someForm.value1}"></c:set>
<c:forTokens items="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" delims="," var="count">
<tr>
<td><input id="field1" name="field1" type="text" value="<c:out value="${input1[count]}" />" onblur="setText2(this)" maxlength="20" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
</c:forTokens>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
```

Second field. This requires value chnage on run when respective value changes for above 10 fields

```
<td valign="top">
<table width="85%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="inputTable">
<tr>
<td width="60%">
<table width="60%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
<c:forTokens items="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9" delims="," var="count">
<tr>
<td><input id="field2" name="field2" type="text"    value="" />" readonly class="readonly" maxlength="1" size="1">
</td>
</tr>
</c:forTokens>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function setText2(element) {
if(element.value)
{
document.getElementById("field2").value = element.value;
}else{
document.getElementById("indicator").value = "";
}
}
</script>
```

This is running fine. But problem is I am able to identified which field is being changed through this but unable to get reference of target field. This changes value of second fields but always in first row of second table.

Please help me to run this so that if a field changes of table1 , then the repective (same serial) field of table 2 should change. I cant change the table structure due to some project limitations.

Comment: You've got multiple html input elements with the same id.  10 elements with id="field1" and 10 elements with id="field2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Tap, assign distinct id for each field (of array). The only thing I want to add is, we should use c:out while assigning number to id as given below (otherwise id will not have numbers as being expected rather it will assign string as "field1_${count}" ):

Use:

```
<input id="<c:out value="field1_${count}" />"  name="field1" type="text" value="<c:out value="${input1[count]}" />"   onblur="setText2(this)" maxlength="20" size="15"/>
```

This runs well!! ;)

I am happy; this solved my big problem without affecting structure of the code...

Thanks a lot again Tap, for your suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` is selecting the first element with id="field2".  You shouldn't give the same id to multiple elements.  Try changing the id to correspond to the count, then in your javascript function you can get the field2 input that corresponds to the count of the blurred input.

Replace your `field1` code with this:

```
 <input id="field1_${count}" name="field1" type="text" value="${input1[count]}"
        onblur="setText2(this)" maxlength="20" size="15"/>
```

Replace your `field2` code with this:

```
<input id="field2_${count}" name="field2" type="text" value="" 
       readonly="readonly" class="readonly" maxlength="1" size="1">
```

Then change your javascript function:

```
    function setText2(element) {
        if(element.value)
        {
            var changedId = element.id;
            var elementNumber = changedId.substring(changedId.indexOf('_') + 1);

            document.getElementById("field2_" + elementNumber).value = element.value;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("indicator").value = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Tap, I tried this option. But unfortunately, document.getElementById("field2_" + elementNumber) does not return the dom object for the filed. I suspect that  id="field1_${count}"  and  id="field2_${count}" are not being assigned to the respective fields. Could you please provide your thoughts on this?

Comment: For Testing purpose I made two fileds with id like field1_0 and field1_1 then document.getElementById("field2_0") and  document.getElementById("field2_1")  work. I think in  id="field1_${count}" count is not evaluated during page load.

Comment: You must have an older servlet/jsp implementation, because c:out isn't necessary these days unless you need to [escape html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574776/in-jstl-jsp-when-do-i-have-to-use-cout-value-myvar-and-when-can-i-just).