# JSTL: Why my data are not being printed in JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, requestdispatcher

Please check the below code, which I attach data into the `RequestDispatcher` from my `Servlet`

```
request.setAttribute("userInfo", userInfo);
            request.setAttribute("userProfession", userProfession);
            request.setAttribute("userQualification", userQualification);
            
            RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/profile.jsp");
            dispatch.forward(request, response);
```

All the attached attributes are `beans`.

In my `JSP`, I get the data as follows.

```
<head>
      <%@taglib prefix="c" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
</head>

<body>
<h5>Name</h5>
<p class="xpanel_txt1"><c out="${userInfo.firstName}"/> <c out=" "/> <c out="${userInfo.lastName}"/></p>
</body>
```

Now the interesting part is, when the website JSP is displayed, I only see a blank field where the above data should be typed. However if I opened the `inspector` in google chrome, I can see the data are already loaded.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue. There was an error in JSTl. The correct way to print is

```
<c:out value="${userInfo.email}"/>
```

I have missed the `value` part in code and the other issues.

Comment: i mention some extra in answer

Answer (score 1):

you should use `c:out` and `value` attribute in jstl tags

```
<head>
          <%@taglib prefix="c" uri= "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h5>Name</h5>
    <p class="xpanel_txt1"><c:out value="${userInfo.firstName}"/> <c:out value=" "/> <c:out value="${userInfo.lastName}"/></p>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, instead of

```
<p class="xpanel_txt1"><c:out value="${userInfo.firstName}"/> <c:out value=" "/> <c:out value="${userInfo.lastName}"/></p>
```

you can display the output using EL directly

```
<p class="xpanel_txt1">${userInfo.firstName} ${userInfo.lastName}</p>
```

For the difference between these two approaches, please refer to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6574812/7873361